# $StateChangeSuccess function not firing when navigating from a child state to a parent state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I am currently implementing a loading page using a custom loading directive on our main page that gets toggled true after the $stateChangeStart event is fired and is toggled false after the $stateChangeSuccess event.  However, whenever I navigate from a child state to its parent, the $stateChangeSuccess event is not fired.  Code sample below:

```
var stateStart = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
    timeout = $timeout(function () {
        $ionicNavBarDelegate.title(findTitle(toState.name));
        $rootScope.loadingState = true;
    }, 50);
});


var stateFinish = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams) {
    $timeout.cancel(timeout);
    $rootScope.loadingState = false;
});
```

Comment: Possible that `$stateChangeCancel` or `$stateChangeError` events were fired instead.

Comment: I tried adding: $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeCancel', function (event) {
  console.log('cancel');
 }); with no effect.  I don't see anything in the current ui-router docs about $stateChangeCancel.  Do I need to do something special for it?

Comment: Where is this code located, the run method or controller constructor function? 
Make sure you are calling those methods at run time, which means you have to move the code to ".run" method and it should be fine.

Comment: It's in a run function already.

Comment: did you find a solution though?

Comment: I think this is happening because you are declaring `expressions`. Try removing `var stateStart` and `var stateFinish`